# How to apply gradient color using FFMPEG library where color fades away to a transparent color from a specific color?

Tags: ffmpeg, terminal

[image: Sample Image]

I want something like the above image.

I have tried this code

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf 
"drawtext=fontfile=Alaska.ttf:text='demo text':fontcolor=black:fontsize=30:box=1
:boxborderw=5:boxcolor=0x483D8B:boxcolor=0x2F4F4F:x=1:y=550:enable='between(t,14,t)'"
-codec:a copy output.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

For this, first add the gradient color and text on trans.png that needs to be written on video using php.

here is trans.png:

---

[image: here is image]

---

```php
        //for video gradient bg
        $name='tmp.png';
        $name_count = strlen($vName);
        $start = 0;
        $stop = $name_count * 20;
        $color_trans = '8F7E9B';

        // if (isset($start) && isset($stop) && isset($color)) {
        $color = hex2rgb($color_trans);
        $range = $stop - $start;

        // create input image
        $input = imagecreatefrompng(PATH . 'trans.png');


        // create output image
        $height = imagesy($input);
        $height = 45;
        $width = imagesx($input);
        $output = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

        // put a transparent background on it
        $trans_colour = imagecolorallocatealpha($output, 0, 0, 0, 127);
        imagefill($output, 0, 0, $trans_colour);

        // create the gradient
        for ($x = 0; $x < $width; ++$x) {
            $alpha = $x <= $start ? 0 : round(min(($x - $start) / $range, 1) * 127);
            
            $new_color = imagecolorallocatealpha($output, $color[0], $color[1], $color[2], $alpha);
            
            imageline($output, $x, $height, $x, 0, $new_color);
        } // copy the gradient onto the input image 
        imagecopyresampled($input, $output, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height);
        // output the result 
        // header('Content-Type: image/png');

        $name = 'trans_' . rand(10, 100) . '.png';
        imagepng($input, PATH . 'temp/' . $name);
        // }
        //--/for video gradient bg
```

Then merge this image with your video

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 ' -i ' . PATH . 'temp/' . $name . ' -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=0:500:enable=between(t\,4\,t)" -codec:a copy ' . PATH . 'videos/video.mp4
```

Comment: You'll want to be very careful with this code... as it stands now, you're allowing arbitrary data to be thrown in on the command line.  A likely severe security issue.

Comment: than can u please suggest how do i do this without security issue @Brad